# jQuery.ajax POST 500 Internal Server Error on PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internal-server-error

I am getting this error on a js function that sends an ajax request to a login script. here is the code:

```
function validateLogin(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginform").submit(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./php/autologin.php",
        data: {
          'login': $("#login").val(), 
          'password': $("#password").val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
          if(data.status === "success"){
            alert(data.message);
            window.location = "./userarea.html?user=".concat(data.user);
          } else if (data.status === "error"){
            alert(data.message);
          }
        },
        error:function(thrownError){
          console.log(thrownError);
        }
      }); 
      return false;
    });

  });
}
```

i am getting a POST 500 Internal Server Error on the url from the above code
and here is what is being printed in the console of chrome:

```
POST http://localhost/capstone/atomos-4.0/php/autologin.php 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
f.extend.ajax jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
(anonymous function) validateLogin.js:4
f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
```

I don't really understand what the post error is trying to tell me, can any one give me a nudge in the right direction to solving this. let me know if you need more info. thanks

EDIT: here is the php function in question:
`autologin.php`

```
include './login.php';

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$loginattempt = json_decode(login($login, $password));

if ($loginattempt->{'status'} === "success") {
  return json_encode(array('status' => "success", 'message' => "Login Successful!"));
  die();
} else { 
  return json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'error' => "loginfailure", 'message' => ($loginattempt -> {"message"})));
  die();
}
?>
```

and `login.php`:

```
<?php

include './connnect_to_mysql.php';

function login($log, $pass) {
  $connection = json_decode(connect_to_mysql());
  if ($connection->{'status'} === "success") {
    $sqlquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE login='$log' AND password='$pass'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($sqlquery) == 1) {
      setcookie("user", $log, 60 * 60 * 24);
      return json_encode(array('status' => "success", 'message' => "Login Successful.", 'user' => $log));
      die();
    } else {
      return json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'error' => "loginfailure", 'message' => mysql_error()));
      die();
    }
  } else {
    return json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'error' => "connectionerror", 'message' => $connection -> {'message'}));
    die();
  }
}

?>
```

EDIT 2:
`connect_to_mysql.php`:

```
<?php

function connect_to_mysql() {
  $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
  if ($con) {
    $db = mysqli_select_db($con, 'db')or die(mysql_error());
    if ($db) {
      return json_encode(array('status' => "success", 'message' => "connected"));
      die();
    }
  } else {
    return json_encode(array('status' => "error", 'message' => mysql_error()));
    die();
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: A server error means something died on the server and nothing was sent back.  I would suggest removing the enormous response text paste, it isn't useful to diagnose the problem and will probably deter people from you question.

Comment: Status 500 means server error, so it is likely in the php script not in your ajax call, but the ajax call might have something to do with it, can you post the php source?

Comment: And you will need to post your PHP code since the error is occurring on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix `include './connnect_to_mysql.php';` to `include './connect_to_mysql.php';` :)

Comment: sorry dude, can you var_dump($_POST)? I think i see it.

Comment: this is what i get from the var_dump($_POST):                  array(2) {
  ["login"]=>
  string(17) "this is my email"
  ["password"]=>
  string(13) "this is my password"
}

Comment: i changed the login and password values but i know they are being entered correctly

Comment: also that was a var_dump from autologin.php, i assumed thats where you wanted it from

Comment: ok, so that looks ok, after `$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());` can you do a `print "mysql not the 500"; exit;` and let me know if it prints the line? I would say var_dump it but i dont know if thats gonna be too much stuff

Comment: okay it doesn't print the line, however the previous print you had me do got rid of the error but the ajax call was still failing, sorry i forgot to mention it before... removing the previous print call returns the error

Comment: hey, check it out, can you do the `print "whatever"; exit;` / `var_dump(somevar);` until you find the culprit? sorry, just dont want to make you come back here every 2 min. Post a reply when you find the offending line, but yes it looks like something in your php script. did you check the mysql_error.log and php error logs (which probably just outputs to the apache log)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12583/discussion-between-ryan-and-joe)

Comment: okay i'll narrow it down some more and post back when i find something, and i'll check the logs to se what they say

Comment: i moved the convo to chat, you gonna join?